# XCode strange behavior

Tags: xcode, xcode6.3

I have strange behavior of XCode, if someone could explain it to me it would be very useful.

So the thing is that I've updated XCode 6.2 to 6.3 at 10th April.
Mac App Store app says that my Xcode is 6.3 now, but Xcode itself says that it is still 6.2 (in the XCode > About Xcode menu).

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Odds on, your Dock has an Xcode from another location on your disk. Right click on the dock icon when it's open, select `Options`, then `Show in Finder`. What's the path to the folder (right click on the title of the Finder window)? If it's not `/Applications`, then drag it off the Dock, and grab the App Store version from `/Applications`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! But it really grabs XCode 6.2 from /Applications. I'll try to completely remove XCode from my Mac and reinstall it from Mac App Store.

Comment: I've reinstalled XCode and now everything seems fine %)